# Mirror desktop icons (only) on multiple monitors

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, desktop

I'm trying to find a way of mirroring my main desktop onto my secondary monitor so that it shows the same icons on both. Anybody know of a way to do this?

Comment: So you're looking to just duplicate the icons?

Comment: Yep, but nothing else. Maybe the wallpaper too, but that's not as important.

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: It can be possible to do refer this link http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-vista/understanding-multiple-monitors

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Windows 8 / 8.1

Comment: @vembutech If you have an answer can you post it. This link no longer seems to work.